# How to prevent the creation of same object using Faker?

Tags: django, factory-boy

I have the following factory:

```
class MonthFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Month

    year = factory.Faker("random_int", min=2014, max=2022)
    month = factory.Faker("random_int", min=1, max=12)
```

Both year and month are unique in my Django class:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (
        "month",
        "year",
    )
```

When I want to create two objects for a test, let's say:

```
month1 = MonthFactory()
month2 = MonthFactory()
```

sometimes I hit the jackpot and get:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

because Faker got the same month and year for both objects.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case for [try/except](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions) using django's database exceptions.  Assuming you don't have other items in the database (if you do, you may need to do this for month1 as well)...

```py
from django.db import IntegrityError

month2 = 0 #set a falsy value flag
while not month2: #keep going until month2 is a truthy thing
    try:
        month2 = MonthFactory()
    except IntegrityError:
        print("Bad luck, trying again")
```

Comment: Yes, that would probably make it, but I am wondering if factory-boy has something for this situation.